# función para mostrar la imagen destacada de la pagina de entradas en WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Muy buenas, querida comunidad.

Estoy desarrollando un theme en wordpress y me he encontrado con el siguiente problema.

quiero mostrar la imagen destacada de la pagina que esta asignada como blog,
el archivo es el home.php, he usado la función:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

De la misma forma que he hecho en el resto de archivos, lo que ocurre es que en esta pagina en concreto, en lugar de mostrar la imagen destacada que asigne desde el panel de wordpress (backend)
lo que me muestra es la imagen destacada de la ultima entrada que se ha añadido.

¿Alguien sabe si hay alguna función especifica para mostrar la imagen destacada de la pagina que esta asignada como blog, o alguna otra forma de mostrar dicha imagen?

Muchas gracias, les dejo el codigo completo.

```
<?php get_header() ?>

<div class="feature">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué quiere decir: *"la pagina que esta asignada como blog"*? ¿A qué te refieres con que la página es `home.php`? ¿Lo que intentas es mostrar el thumbnail de `home.php` o qué? ¿Desde dónde estás intentando correr tu código?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando asignas una pagina para las entradas wordpress automáticamente anula las plantillas personalizadas, por lo que pasa a usar index.php o home.php, según tengas asignado.

Cuando llamas a la función `the_post_thumbnail()` esta en vez de conectarse al loop de la pagina lo hace al loop de los post, por eso obtienes la imagen de la primera entrada, al ser esta pagina recopilatorio no podrás acceder a esa imagen, almenos que resetees el loop usando `wp_reset_postdata()` al final del `while`.

Si esto no funciona puedes usar la función `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` y pasarle el id de la pagina, entonces puedes hacer algo como esto.

```
// Obtener la imagen de la pagina por su ID
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 566, 'full' );

// Mostrarlo en pantalla
echo '<img src="' . $image['0'] . '">';
```

Esto debería traer la imagen de la pagina actual sin afectar al loop.

Comment: Muy buenas @jefferzonBol , muchas gracias por tu ayuda, no me funciono, pero aprecio mucho que te hayas tomado el tiempo de responder y ayudar. La solución momentánea ha asido deshabilitar el blog como pagina de entradas y hacerla una pagina normal.